# configuration maxSemaphores for zuul server

Tags: netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix

I am trying to do load test for zuul `version 1.1.2`.

However I am keep getting following issue after few a minute for running load test.

```
Caused by: com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: book could not acquire a semaphore for execution and no fallback available.
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$21.call(AbstractCommand.java:783) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
```

My question is how can I increase `maxSemaphores` via confiugration.

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds= 20000000
zuul.hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.strategy= SEMAPHORE
zuul.hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.semaphore.maxConcurrentRequests= 10
zuul.hystrix.command.default.fallback.isolation.semaphore.maxConcurrentRequests= 10
zuul.semaphore.maxSemaphores=3000
```

**zuul.eureka.book.semaphore.maxSemaphore=30000**

I have tried search many option on Intenet but one of those works for me

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

it turns out I am using old version. For later version we could set semaphores at Zuul level. below is an example to set the maxSemaphores 3000 as default for routing to every proxied service

**zuul.semaphore.maxSemaphores=3000**

Answer (score 0):

The actual property is max-semaphores (this would be with yaml config):

```
zuul:
  semaphore:
    #com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: "microservice" could not acquire a semaphore for execution and no fallback available.
    max-semaphores: 2000
```